# Separating service and front-end in AppEngine causes latency

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, architecture, latency

I have a set of Java AppEngine apps structured as follows:

- REST service
- Web Frontend

These two components are hosted on 2 separate AppEngine instances (paid), this is a standard way to design you application, and makes sense for me since I access the REST service from other clients too (mobile apps, etc.) so I'd like to keep it separate.

The issue I have is that, even though if I access the REST service directly (GET from browser or mobile apps) responsiveness is always good, when accessing the REST service from my AppEngine front-end response time is sometimes very erratic.

I ran a bunch of tests and while doing GETs from the browser to the REST service always returns reasonably fast, calls from  my AppEngine front-end to the REST service could go from returning as fast as from the browser to taking up to >10 seconds (causing time-outs etc.) with not so reasonable response-times in general (secs instead of 100s of msecs).

If there was latency in general, I can understand everything would on average take pretty much the same time to get a response, but what I don't understand is this difference between calling the service from anywhere else and calling it **from** an AppEngine instance.

I have to say this does not happen always, goes well for weeks and then there are some very bad days (today does't really count as it was a [full blow outage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6miG.png)), and, even though in general I am very happy about app-engine, makes me sometimes wonder if I made a mistake investing on this platform.

I am looking for an explanation: **is this some kind of inherent AppEngine limitation when queuing this kind of pretty standard http-requests outgoing from an AppEngine instance?**

Also I have been thinking about possible work-arounds - maybe I should host the service into the same instance as the front-end, but I really don't wanna do that and I am leaving it as last resort.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: "This is a standard way to design [your] application" [citation needed] - it's really not, and as you're observing, it's a particularly inefficient way to design your application.

Comment: @NickJohnson Hi Nick, why so defensive? If not a best-practice, it certainly is an industry standard to design your app to separate service from front-end on all the other platforms I have ever worked on. Response time when invoking the service from anywhere but an AppEngine instance is in fact just OK and fairly reliable. I'd like your input with regards to why, as I am observing, this is particularly inefficient when calling the service **FROM** an AppEngine instance. Are you suggesting the only solution to this is to pull the service into the same instance as the front-end?

Comment: @NickJohnson I do not agree with your statement.  Besides that, where is your citation for saying it is not a standard way.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 reasons

1.External Access to your REST Service , caching is optimized as the client(s) are various versions of browsers. Your FrontEnd application which is internally accessing REST Service might not implemented a very good caching mechanism.

2.Does AppEngine bill for Internal Traffic ? if Not, then that might be reason for giving extenal IPs priority than internal??

Comment: Thanks for your answer: 1. I would imagine this is something intrinsic to AppEngine, so it falls under the possible explanations but I have no idea if this is the case or not. 2. appEngine charges for outgoing bandwidth (regardless) and I am contacting the service via http so traffic is not "internal".